# NavigateCommand only called once

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, windows-store-apps, mvvm-light

In order to familiarize myself with MVVM for WinRT I have been looking at the example MvvmLight WinRT project. Currently I'm running into an issue where my RelayCommand is only called once (on construction of viewmodel). What I want to do is go to the MainViewModel if the user is authorized. If I remove the conditional check of the login in the LoginCommand method, the RelayCommand works as expected. Any thoughts as to what I'm doing wrong? Should I not being doing my validation within the LoginCommand?

LoginViewModel (some code has been removed):

```
public class LoginViewModel : ViewModelBase {
  private readonly IDataService _dataService;
  private readonly INavigationService _navigationService;

  private RelayCommand _navigateCommand;
  private Login login; //contains username and password

  /// <summary>
  /// Gets the NavigateCommand.
  /// THIS DOES NOT GET FIRED UPON BUTTON CLICK
  /// </summary>
  public RelayCommand LoginCommand{
     get {
        if (login != null && login.UserName.Equals("Test"))
           return _navigateCommand ?? (_navigateCommand = new RelayCommand(() => _navigationService.Navigate(typeof(MainPage))));
        return _navigateCommand;
     }
  }
```

LoginPage.xaml.cs (some code has been removed):

```
public sealed partial class LoginPage {
  public LoginViewModel Vm {
     get { return (LoginViewModel)DataContext; }
  }

  public LoginPage() {
     InitializeComponent();
  }

  protected override void LoadState(object state) {
     var casted = state as LoginPageState;

     if (casted != null) {
        Vm.Load(casted);
     }
  }

  protected override object SaveState() {
     return new LoginPageState {
        Credentials = new Login {
           UserName = txtUserName.Text,
           Password = txtPassword.Text
        }
     };
  }

  public class LoginPageState {
      public Login Credentials { get; set; }
      }
  }
}
```

LoginPage.xaml (some code has been removed)

```
<Button Content="Login"
            x:Name="NextPageButton"
            HorizontalAlignment="Right"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Margin="10"
            Command="{Binding LoginCommand}" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the condition. When your `LoginPage` loads, it tries to bind your `Button` to the `LoginCommand`. In order to achieve that, it gets the `LoginCommand` from your `ViewModel`. At that point in time `Login` is null and therefore the property will return `_navigateCommand` which is `null`. After that the page will not try to use the `LoginCommand`  because it already knows its value.

To solve this you could move the condition inside the lambda expression:

```
public RelayCommand LoginCommand
{
    get
    {
        return _navigateCommand ?? (_navigateCommand = new RelayCommand(
            () =>
            {
                if (login != null && login.UserName.Equals("Test"))
                {
                    _navigationService.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
                }
            }));
    }
}
```

An even better solution would be to move the authorization to another class. Something like:

```
public RelayCommand LoginCommand
{
    get
    {
        return _navigateCommand ?? (_navigateCommand = new RelayCommand(
            () =>
            {
                if (_authorizationService.UserAuthorized(login))
                {
                    _navigationService.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
                }
            }));
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It's still not working, I think another issue might be within the binding of the model and the view. Is there a best practice for updating the model behind the view?